# String.Format() destroing skype link

Tags: c#, hyperlink, string.format

I have a problem with `String.Format()`. There are some email letters in .htm format, which I read and insert needed parameters using `String.Format()`. In letter I use skype links like `<a href="skype:{0}?chat">Skype</a>`, where `{0}` - Skype name. After sending, user gets letter with such link `<a>Skype</a>`, without `href` part. What do I do wrong?

Code:

Here I send letter

`path` - path to .htm file with letter template

```
SmtpProviderService.SendEmail(email, subject, string.Format(File.ReadAllText(path), mailParameters), false);
```

.htm file contains this string

```
<td style="border:0"><a href="skype:{0}?chat">{0}</a></td>
```

`{0}` - first parameter in `mailParameters`

Comment: can you show us your relevant code ? how are you constructing this string and sending it ?

Comment: `string.Format` isn't doing that; I think you need to debug, looking at the value returned from various locations between when you first call string.Format, through to where you render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, the first step is to debug; add code:

```
string template = File.ReadAllText(path);
string finalHtml = string.Format(template, mailParameters);
SmtpProviderService.SendEmail(email, subject, finalHtml, false);
```

now put a break-point on the third line, and *inspect the value of `finalHtml`*. I strongly suspect you'll find that it is intact, meaning: the problem is somewhere inside `SendEmail`. If `finalHtml` is **not** intact, I strongly suggest you look at the value of `template`, to check that it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks, String.Fromat doing it right. It's all about SendEmail. Sorry for stupid question, I'm just beginner and sometimes can forget about such usefull thing as normal debugging:)